# Formation of stars

Tags: star

How are stars formed? 
I read somewhere that when dust, gas, rocks etc come close to each other due to gravity, slowly and gradually build up a lot of pressure and form stars. 
If what I read is right, then from where did these materials come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all starts in a [molecular cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud), which are clouds in space with high densities. They can contain all kind of gases and [dust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_dust) and also due to their densities and relatively low temperatures they also contain molecules like H2, CO2 and H2O. These are in a thermodynamic equilibrium until something disturbs them (usually nearby supernovae). For some reason a zone of this cloud becomes denser and gravity wins to and starts to collapse the cloud until it forms a star.

These molecular clouds can be the remains of dead stars or simply a bunch of gas and dust collected and hold at the high-density zones at the galaxy's spiral arms or around the core.